# problema con multi query PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hola gente no se porqué este código no me funciona (imprime "no se puede crear la fecha") y he visto en internet que las multiquery se hacen de esta forma, acá les dejo lo que hice, saludos

> *ACLARACIÓN: esto es la parte de un método.. pero creo que no es necesario adjuntarlo por completo
>
> *los echo son a modo de testeo para ver a cual condicional entra

```
if (!$this->conectar()){return 0 ;} // no se pudo conectar a la bd
 $i=1;
 $query="INSERT INTO partido (num_partido,num_fecha) VALUES ($i,$numfecha)";
for ($i=2;$i<=15;$i++)
     {$query.="INSERT INTO partido (num_partido,num_fecha) VALUES ($i,$numfecha)";}
  if ($this->mysqli->multi_query($query)) { echo "la fecha fue creada exitosamente";}
  else {echo "no se pudo crear la fecha :(";}
}
```

Comment: No he usado esa instrucción pero en http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php se muestra un "next_result()" así mismo en el fragmento de código que muestras no estás colocando el punto y como ";" al final de cada sentencia; cada sentencia debe tener su delimitador de fin (en este caso ";") del SQL a ejecutarse.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas pero si los ";" están puesto, donde decís que me faltan?? si me faltase alguno el código no se ejecutaría , lo de next_result() voy a probar a ver como funciona pero tenia entendido que era para recuperar el resultado de varias consultas.. no se si es para cuando insertas datos

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas mirá este ejemplo https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp no usa next_result()

Comment: PHP no te muestra error porque el problema es de SQL. Como te han dicho, faltan el punto y coma delimitador al final de cada sentencia SQL, antes de la comillas de cierre: ```...VALUES ($i, $numfecha);";```.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas  tienen razon ya me anduvo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con este código:

**EDIT:**

He probado el código y funciona. Con respecto a la `$query` funcionaría rodeando cada variable por comillas simples `' '`, asumiendo que para construir **toda** la cadena SQL usas comillas dobles: `"`.

**Pero**, para evitar sorpresas, **es mejor enviar los datos del tipo que son**, si enteros, enteros, si cadenas, cadenas. Es decir, si cualquiera de las dos variables es un entero, mejor convertirla a entero:

```
$i = int ($i);
$numfecha = int ($numfecha);
```

Y luego, es mejor también construir nuestra cadena `INSERT` como haríamos en MySQL.

a. Si el valor es una cadena, encerrar la variable con `'$variable'`

b. Si el valor es un entero, ponerla sin `' '` alrededor

Si en tu caso `num_partido` y `num_fecha`son enteros:

```
$query="INSERT INTO partido (num_partido,num_fecha) VALUES ($i,$numfecha);";
```

Si  `num_partido` y `num_fecha` son cadenas:

```
$query="INSERT INTO partido (num_partido,num_fecha) VALUES ('$i','$numfecha');";
```

Si  `num_partido` es cadena y `num_fecha` entero:

```
$query="INSERT INTO partido (num_partido,num_fecha) VALUES ('$i',$numfecha);";
```

Si  `num_partido` es entero y `num_fecha` cadena:

```
$query="INSERT INTO partido (num_partido,num_fecha) VALUES ($i,'$numfecha');";
```

Ya con esto, el resto de código no debería darte problema:

```
<?php
//    $query="INSERT INTO partido (num_partido,num_fecha) VALUES ($i,$numfecha);";
//Crear la $query como se ha indicado arriba, según el caso 

// Ejecutar SQL
$i = 0;
if( $this->mysqli->multi_query( $query ) )
{
    do {
        $this->mysqli->next_result();
        $i++;
    }
    while( $this->mysqli->more_results() ); 
}

if( $this->mysqli->errno )
{
    die(
        '<h1>ERROR</h1>
        Consulta #' . ( $i + 1 ) . '</pre><br /><br /> 
        <span style="color:red;">' . $this->mysqli->error . '</span>'
    );
}
?>
```

**Nota**

[Las contribuciones del Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php) indican varios problemas cuando se usa multi-query. Yo recomendaría usar [PDO y sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) si es posible, además, se pueden insertar múltiples valores usando sentencias preparadas.

Comment: ahora lo testeo y te aviso, aprovecho a preguntarte  como hago para que dos columnas sean distintas porque tengo que sacar los "idequipo1" "idequipo2" de la tabla equipos y necesito hacer que no aparezca el mismo idequipo en una fila , no se si me explico??

Comment: @fer He actualizado la respuesta, después de haber probado el código. Te debería funcionar si tomas en cuenta lo que he explicado con más detalle sobre los tipos de datos. Saludos.

Comment: @fer no he entendido lo que preguntas sobre los idequipos. Generalmente las tablas en bases de datos contienen una fila por id aunque luego al obtener los datos puedes presentar filas como columnas haciendo JOINS. No sé si te refieres a eso. En cualquier caso lo importante es que en el origen los datos estén organizados siguiendo las reglas

Comment: estuve viendo que es mejor usar las sentencias preparadas como me mencionaron acá , de todas formas para la verificación de los enteros uso "is_numeric" en la primera linea del método, es decir que sino cumple eso ya no se ejecuta nada del resto, saludos

Comment: lo que digo del idequipo es que yo en la tabla partido tengo "2 equipos que juegan" los cuales los identifico con ID (de la tabla equipos) y quería saber si hay una forma de restringir en MYSQL para que el Idequipo1 sea si o si diferente al Idequipo2 ( que el mismo equipo no pueda enfrentarse a si mismo jaja)

Comment: @fer pues eso de los equipos que dices sería objeto de una interesante pregunta aquí en esSO. Sugiero que intentes resolver el problema planteado aquí y que escribas otra pregunta, creo que es algo que por un lado es complicado resolverlo en comentarios y por otro, si se le dedica una pregunta podría ser útil a más de uno y seguro que vas a obtener varias respuestas interesantes y útiles. Además no es bueno resolver varias preguntas en una. Saludos.