# Funcion de Php inserta en MySql solo cuando la tabla esta vacia

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hola tengo la siguiente funcion de php que al llamarla hace una llamada a un proceso de MySql. el problema es que solo inserta los datos cuando la tabla esta vacia. Estoy usando Xampp, si llamo al proceso directamente desde PhpMyAdmin no hay problema, el problema es solo cuando llamo a la funcion desde el navegador usando:

localhost/dataBaseTests/getPromotionalCode.php?name=unnombre&email=unemail

La funcion que llamo :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la funcion ejecutarSQLCommand:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías proporcionar igual la estructura de la tabla

Comment: No usas en ningún momento el método `execute` de MySQLi, que es el encargado de enviar tu consulta. Por otro lado es más útil cuando posteas una pregunta poner el texto del código y no una imagen. Desde el teléfono es difícil ver las imágenes.

Comment: ¿Donde deberia usar ese metodo? ¿Dentro de la consulta de Mysql? porque la consulta funciona bien al llamarla cuando la tabla esta vacia, se insertan los datos correctamente. una vez que la tabla tiene algun dato la consulta deja de funcionar

Comment: esta es la estructura de la tabla https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxFDV.png

Comment: No vi que estabas usando `multi_query`. Entonces el problema es que `store_result()` devuelve falso si lo invocas para consultas del tipo  `INSERT...` u otras que no devuelvan resultados o si hay algún otro error. Entonces el código no está entrando en el `while...`. Si lees en el [Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.store-result.php) verás: _mysqli_store_result() devuelve FALSE en caso de que la consulta no devuelve un conjunto de resultados (si la consulta era, por ejemplo, una sentencia INSERT). Esta función también devuelve FALSE si la lectura del conjunto de resultados falla_

Comment: ¿entonces deberia sustituir  "multi_query" por el metodo "execute"?

Comment: Además, la cadena misma del `INSERT` podría darte problemas. Hace probé un código usando `multi_query` en el que, si usaba variables de PHP debía encerrar cada `'$variable'` entre comillas simples, de lo contrario el código fallaba. Lo explico con más detalle [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64741/29967)

Comment: No, cuando se usa `multi_query` no hace falta `execute`, ya que `multi_query` es una especie de `execute`. Revisa esa condicional que tienes usando `store_result()` la cual en este caso será siempre falsa, y también lo que te decía de encerrar las variables por comillas simples. Para que no haya problemas, debes empezar y terminar el insert con comillas dobles `"INSERT... "` así podrás usar dentro las comillas simples para rodear cada nombre de variable PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace poco probé el uso de inserciones usando `multi_query()` y en ocasiones el código fallaba.

Cuando se usa `multi_query()` hay que tener en cuenta el tipo de dato que estamos tratando de insertar.

Supongamos esta cadena de inserción:

```
$query="INSERT INTO tabla (columna_int,columna_str) VALUES ($i,$str);";
```

Para enviar esta cadena por `multi_query()` y no tener un error, es necesario encerrar entre comillas simples **todas las variables que contengan valores del tipo cadena**, en el caso del ejemplo: `'$str'`

Para las variables que sean enteros, no hace falta. Pero hay algo en lo que a veces fallamos con los enteros, si `$int` está destinada a una columna del tipo `entero`de nuestra base de datos, lo correcto es enviársela convertida en entero, y sin encerrar entre comillas simples. Si queremos podemos enviarla como una cadena, quizá funcione, pero **no es correcto**.

Nótese también que debemos **empezar y terminar la sentencia SQL por comillas dobles (`"`)**, para que no haya conflicto con las comillas simples que habrá dentro de la cadena SQL.

También el Manual de PHP (ver enlace al final) dice que `multi_query`:

> Ejecuta una o múltiples consultas **concatenadas por puntos y comas**.

por tanto, cada consulta debe **terminar con punto y coma (`;`)**.

Entonces la `$query` quedaría así:

```
$query="INSERT INTO tabla (columna_int,columna_str) VALUES ($i,'$str');";
```

También hay que usar adecuadamente: `next_result()` y `more_results()`.
El Manual dice que:

> Para obtener el juego de resultados de la primera consulta se puede
>   usar `mysqli_use_result()` o `mysqli_store_result()`. El resto de
>   resultados de consultas se pueden obtener usando `mysqli_more_results()`
>   y `mysqli_next_result()`.

**Código de ejemplo probado y funcional:**

```
<?php
$query="INSERT INTO tabla (columna_int,columna_str) VALUES ($i,'$str');";

// Ejecutar SQL
$i = 0;
if( $this->mysqli->multi_query( $query ) )
{
    do {
        $this->mysqli->next_result();
        $i++;
    }
    while( $this->mysqli->more_results() ); 
}

if( $this->mysqli->errno )
{
    die(
        '<h1>ERROR</h1>
        Consulta #' . ( $i + 1 ) . '</pre><br /><br /> 
        <span style="color:red;">' . $this->mysqli->error . '</span>'
    );
}
?>
```

- Ver: **[`multi_query` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php)**