# query me inserta un solo valor Mysql - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

hola gente tengo un problema, con esta query:

```
   INSERT INTO resultado(idpartido) SELECT idpartido FROM partido where idpartido not in (SELECT idpartido FROM resultado)
```

el problema es que del lado de PHP cuando la ejecuto me inserta 1 sola fila, en cambio si pongo esa consulta en MYSQL me inserta todos los registros (como quiero que sea),  me surge la duda de por qué hace esto??

ADJUNTO EL METODO de lado de php

```
public function crear_fecha ($numfecha,$array_locales,$array_visitantes)
{ 
 if (is_numeric($numfecha) && $numfecha<=30)
{if (!$this->conectar()){return 0 ;} // no se pudo conectar a la bd
 $i=1;
 $p=0;
 $query="INSERT INTO partido (num_partido,num_fecha,idequipo_local,idequipo_visitante) VALUES ($i,$numfecha,$array_locales[$p],$array_visitantes[$p]);";

for ($i=2;$i<=15;$i++)
     {$p++;
      $query.="INSERT INTO partido (num_partido,num_fecha,idequipo_local,idequipo_visitante) VALUES ($i,$numfecha,$array_locales[$p],$array_visitantes[$p]);";
    }
  if ($this->mysqli->multi_query($query))
   { echo "la fecha fue creada exitosamente";
     $query2="INSERT INTO resultado(idpartido) SELECT idpartido FROM partido where idpartido not in (SELECT idpartido FROM resultado)";
     if ($this->mysqli->query($query2))
      {echo "la tabla resultados fue exitosa";
       $asignar_idresultado = "UPDATE partido set idresultado = (select idresultado from resultado WHERE resultado.idpartido = partido.idpartido)";
       if ($this->mysqli->query($asignar_idresultado))
         {echo "los ids se asignaron correctamente";}
      }
   }
  else {echo "no se pudo crear la fecha :(";}
  }


}
```

Comment: Si pudieras añadir el codigo php

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda ahí agregue el código , saludos

Comment: Para que `multi_query ` funcione necesitas usar también `next_result()` y `more_results`, más o menos como se explica en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64741/29967). Toma nota de lo que se dice sobre el tipo de dato, si es un entero o una cadena. En la sentencia SQL las variables de tipo `'$cadena'` deben ir rodeadas de comillas simples, y toda la sentencia `$query="INSERT INTO .... ;"` debe ir rodeada de comillas dobles  y tener un `;` antes de la comilla de cierre.

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda el tema es que la multiquery me está funcionando con ese código, de todas formas voy a hacer esas modificaciones

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas resuelto. La puedes eliminar tú mismo.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque el OP encontró una solución y no parece estar dispuesto a compartir el código con la misma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disculpen, soy nuevo en el foro y no se bien como es la metodología del cierre de preguntas y demás. Bueno como decía, lo pude solucionar y aporto el código para alguno que le pueda servir.

> Lo que hice fue concatenar las querys en una sola y luego usar multi_query, con esto me inserta los datos y actualiza en una sola consulta

```
public function crear_fecha ($numfecha,$array_locales,$array_visitantes)
{
 if (is_numeric($numfecha) && $numfecha<=30)
{if (!$this->conectar()){return 0 ;} // no se pudo conectar a la bd
 $i=1;
 $p=0;
 $query="INSERT INTO partido (num_partido,num_fecha,idequipo_local,idequipo_visitante) VALUES ($i,$numfecha,$array_locales[$p],$array_visitantes[$p]);";

for ($i=2;$i<=15;$i++)
     {$p++;
      $query.="INSERT INTO partido (num_partido,num_fecha,idequipo_local,idequipo_visitante) VALUES ($i,$numfecha,$array_locales[$p],$array_visitantes[$p]);";
    }
  $query.="INSERT INTO resultado(idpartido) SELECT idpartido FROM partido where idpartido not in (SELECT idpartido FROM resultado);";
  $query.="UPDATE partido set idresultado = (select idresultado from resultado WHERE resultado.idpartido = partido.idpartido)";
  if ($this->mysqli->multi_query($query))
   { echo "la fecha fue creada exitosamente";
    echo "se asignaron los ids resultados en ambas tablas";
   }
  else {echo "no se pudo crear la fecha :(";}
   }


}
```

saludos, desde ya mil disculpas por no saber la metodología de cierre de preguntas